# .NET type with a "2" suffix?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I vaguely remember there is a .NET type name with the suffix "2". I can't remember exactly which one it is though. Can anyone point it out to me? Thanks

Comment: This is easily the most bizarre question I've ever seen on this site.

Comment: It's a valid and extremely vague question.  Wonder how many answers we can come up with..

Comment: OH NOES, they violate our code guidelines. Guess I can't use them ;)

Comment: @Beska, I think somebody is trying to win a bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple: [ITypeLib2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypelib2.aspx), [ITypeInfo2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221565.aspx), [RC2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rc2.aspx), [IDesignerLoaderHost2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.idesignerloaderhost2.aspx), and [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx).

Comment: Snarky additions: `Int32`, `UInt32`, `HMACSHA512`, `SHA512`, `BitVector32`, `SqlInt32`...

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of them...For example some of the code extensibility uses this.

We're going to need some more information for the specific type you want because there are far more than one of these types of objects.

[CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel(VS.80).aspx) to [CodeModel2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codemodel2(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

At one time there was a plan to add DateTime2, but it was later renamed DateTimeOffset. See [BCL blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/06/18/a-brief-history-of-datetime-anthony-moore.aspx) for details.